# Attempts to access rapidAPI yahoo finance give me error 403 through swift

Tags: swift, api, yahoo-finance, rapidapi

I am trying to use rapidAPI to access the Yahoo Finance API for a personal project. I registered for a free account and got an API key. Rapid API allows their users to copy and paste code to request data, so I took their demo code for accessing the API. Here it is for swift when trying to access details about a stock:

```
import Foundation

let headers = [
"x-rapidapi-host": "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
"x-rapidapi-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" //private key 
]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance- 
v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/get-detail?region=US&lang=en&symbol=APPL")! as URL,
                                    cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse)
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

When I run this code, it gives me error 403. This means that this data is forbidden according to their [website](https://developer.expediapartnersolutions.com/reference/rapid-error-responses/). I have tried using other APIs and copying and pasting the demo code and they work fine. This API shouldn't be depreciated because it is running on the website demo. Here is the returning message I was given in Xcode:
[image: Returning Message]

Comment: facing a similar probel here, did you find out what the problem was ?

Comment: @ishaym Sadly, no. I think that this API might be deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked [Yahoo Finance](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1/) API. The GET /get-detail endpoint seems to be deprecated now. Despite the fact that it's deprecated, it's still working for me.

Make sure to subscribe to this API. this could be the cause of the 403 code